# Cant write 1 byte at the entry point of a process dll module

Tags: c#, winapi, memory, process, byte

**Hello**
so my problem is kind of weird ..
im trying to write memory using this :

```
WriteProcessMemory(intptr pHandle, intptr lpBaseAddr, byte[] lpBuffer, uint nSize, int lpNbrOfBytesWritten);
```

have a process called : proc.exe 
this process has lots of modules .

the module thatbim intersted in called mod.dll.

so what im trying to do here is : 
write the first byte of the entry point which has opcode : **dec ebp**   which equals D4 ithink  as a  1 byte .

so first of all i get the process[0].modules list ...  find my mod.dll in tbat list .. get it's baseAddress then thats it .

since  that address is the entry point addr right ?

so then i made an array of bytes which basically hold just 1 byte : **0xC3** which is a **ret** .
so it should be fine .
but sadly it returns false somehow ... and when i do it manually via **olleDbg**  it works fine.

then i thought i might have made a mistake  while coding ... so i tried  writing memory at  another module  .. with diffrent address of just this time not at  right at the entry point .. was somehing like testmod.dll+4E..

which had 5 bytes his time ..
So yeah i  made 1st byte as C3 and rest as NOPs or 90s ... and it worked fine .

**CODE :**

```
 try
        {
            if ((p = mem.OpenProcess(MY_ACCESS.PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, mem.GetProcess("proc")[0].Id)) != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                //Mod base address
                int z       = (int)get_Mod_BaseAddr("proc", "mod.dll");
                string s    = Convert.ToString(z, 16);
                int zz      = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
                WINTR_Z     += zz; // wintr_z had 0x0 before

                //WINTR_C
                WINTR       += WINTR_Z; // WINTR had 0xFA... before

                //STTER
                z           = (int)get_Mod_BaseAddr("proc", "mod1.dll");
                s           = Convert.ToString(z, 16);
                zz          = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
                STTER       += zz; // WINTR had 0xsome_hex... before


                byte[] _BYP_WINTR_Z = { 0xC3 }; // (does not work)the ret to override dec ebp
                byte[] _BYP_WINTR   = { 0xC3, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90 }; // same module (mod.dll) but diffrent address writing 5 bytes here works fine
                byte[] _BYP_STTER   = { 0xC3, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90 }; // diffrent module (mod1)  writing 5 bytes also works fine .



                if (!mem.WriteProcessMemory(p, (IntPtr)WINTR_Z, _BYP_WINTR_Z, (uint)_BYP_WINTR_Z.Length, 0)) return false; // does not Work(false)
                if (!mem.WriteProcessMemory(p, (IntPtr)WINTR, _BYP_WINTR, (uint)_BYP_WINTR.Length, 0)) return false; // works(true)
                if (!mem.WriteProcessMemory(p, (IntPtr)STTER, _BYP_STTER, (uint)_BYP_STTER.Length, 0)) return false; // works(true)

                return true;
            }

        }
```

**any help please** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`VirtualProtectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualprotectex) before `WriteProcessMemory`, to change the protection on a region of committed pages in the virtual address space of a specified process. like,

```
VirtualProtectEx(p, (IntPtr)WINTR_Z, dwSize, PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY, ref OldProtect)
```

Comment: Hey let me try this .
i believe  page_exe_writecopy defined as 0x80 ?

Comment: > THANKS A LOT !!
Realy worked fine  liek a charm !
Cheers man ur a  damn life saver .